# How to create a function to connect to mysql database and display value?

Tags: java, mysql, database

I want to create a function in a public class to get MySQL connection and display result I try but it's not working for this is my code when I try this code in the main like traditional way it's work but when I try to put it in function nothing appear no error and no result :

```
import java.sql.*;

/**
 *
 * @author hammoudi
 */
public class Getconnection {
    Connection myConn = null;
        Statement myStmt = null;
        ResultSet myRs = null;
        String user = "root";
        String pass = "";
    public void serverconnection() throws SQLException {
        try {

         myConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/soccer", user, pass);


    } catch (Exception exc) {
        } finally {
    if (myConn != null) {
                myConn.close();
            }
}
}
    public void stm() throws SQLException  {
        try {
            myStmt = myConn.createStatement();
            } catch (Exception exc) {
        } finally {
             if (myStmt != null) {
                myStmt.close();
            }
        }
    }
    public void sqlresult() throws SQLException {
        try {
          myRs = myStmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM `real madrid`");
          while (myRs.next()) {
                System.out.println(myRs.getString("FirstName") + ", " + myRs.getString("LastName"));
            }
          } catch (Exception exc) {
        } finally {
          if (myRs != null) {
                myRs.close();
            }

    }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {

        Getconnection connect=new Getconnection();
        connect.serverconnection();
        connect.stm();
        connect.sqlresult();
    }
}
```

Comment: You do have exceptions. You just swallow them silently!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're missing `Class.forName`, try to add it like this:

```
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
   myConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/soccer", user, pass);
```

Answer (score -1):

//You should try this

```
static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/soccer";


static final String USER = "root";
static final String PASS = "";
static Connection conn = null;
public static void connect() {

    try {
        Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception {
    connect();
    if (conn != null)
        return conn;
    else {
        throw new Exception("Can not connect");
    }
}}
```

Answer (score -1):

you should first establish the connection, try this:

place this line

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

Before this line

```
myConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/soccer", user, pass);
```

Happy coding!!

Comment: why you me downvote, your answer equal to mine

Comment: Sorry dude I did it by mistake, I tried to recover it. But my vote is now locked for this.